# How to convert integer to byte array in php

Tags: php, arrays

how would I convert an integer to an array of 4 bytes?

Here is the exact code I want to port (in C#)

```
int i = 123456;
byte[] ar = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
// ar will contain {64, 226, 1, 0}
```

How would I do the exact same thing in PHP ?

Comment: Are you looking for the result to be an array containing the *decimal numbers* 64, 226 etc? Or are you actually looking for the *bytes*, which in PHP would be a string?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The equivalent conversion is

```
$i = 123456;
$ar = unpack("C*", pack("L", $i));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/rikaX)**.

You should be aware though that the byte order (little/big endian) is dependent on the machine architecture (as it is also in the case of `BitConverter`). That might or might not be good.

Answer (score 6):

Since the equivalent of a byte array in PHP is a string, this'll do:

```
$bytes = pack('L', 123456);
```

To visualize that, use `bin2hex`:

```
echo bin2hex($bytes);
// 40e20100
// (meaning 64, 226, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Might be true. But I still needed the single bytes in a array. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user `echo $bytes[0], $byte[1], $byte[2], $byte[3];` PHP strings *are* in essence byte arrays.

Comment: Oh, ok! Excuse my ignorance then. Now that you mention it, I think that I might be overcomplicating things A LOT in PHP...

Comment: @user1392060 If you want single bytes in an array you could try `str_split($bytes)`.