# How to convert byte array to integer in php?

Tags: php

I have seen a code that **converts integer into byte array**. Below is the code on **How to convert integer to byte array in php 3** ([How to convert integer to byte array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544821/how-to-convert-integer-to-byte-array-in-php)):

```
<?php

$i = 123456;
$ar = unpack("C*", pack("L", $i));

print_r($ar);
?>
```

The above code will output:

```
//output:
Array
(
   [1] => 64
   [2] => 226
   [3] => 1
   [4] => 0
)
```

But my problem right now is how to **reverse** this process. Meaning converting from **byte array into integer**. In the case above, the output will be **123456**

Can anybody help me with this. I would be a great help. Thanks ahead.

Comment: try to type casting for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverting unpack('C\*', "string")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357008/reverting-unpackc-string)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php) is how to covert byte array into float in PHP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not treat it like the math problem it is?

```php
$i = ($ar[3]<<24) + ($ar[2]<<16) + ($ar[1]<<8) + $ar[0];
```

Comment: wow, this solve my problem but I change the code into:

$i = ($ar[4]<<24) + ($ar[3]<<16) + ($ar[2]<<8) + ($ar[1]); 

since $ar[0] doesn't exist and when no parentheses is added between plus sign it will return 0 value. but thanks.

Comment: @gchimuel The parentheses around last part `$ar[0]` is unnecessary, other parts is.

Answer (score 5):

Since L is four bytes long, you know the number of elements of the array. Therefore you can simply perform the operation is reverse:

```
$ar = [64,226,1,0];
$i = unpack("L",pack("C*",$ar[3],$ar[2],$ar[1],$ar[0]));
```

Comment: You can also do `unpack('L', pack('C*', ...array_reverse($ar)))` if you can ensure that $ar have 4 items and being indexed from 0 to 3.

Comment: Also note the output of `unpack('C*', $someBytesArray)` will starts index from 1, so you should wrap `array_values()` on it.

Comment: The meaning of `array_reverse()` or writing literal `$ar[3], ..., $ar[0]` is to convert byte order between big and small endian, if you can ensure the same endian is used through `pack()` to `unpack()`, you don't have to reverse them.

Answer (score 4):

In order to get a signed 4-byte value in PHP you need to do this:

```php
    $temp = ($ar[0]<<24) + ($ar[1]<<16) + ($ar[2]<<8) + $ar[3];
    if($temp >= 2147483648)
         $temp -= 4294967296;
```

Comment: Worth to mention that this workaround is needed for `x64` builds of PHP (except Windows ones). And there is one mistake in the code. The comparison must be `greater or equal` instead of just `greater`.