# Reverting unpack('C*', "string")

Tags: php, pack, unpack

I would like to know how I can reverse what this [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) function bellow performed. I think the [pack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function is able to reverse what [unpack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) performed, however I'm not sure.

First I have a simple string which after unpacking it I would have an array of bytes representing such string. Now I would like to know how to reverse such array back to the original string.

```
<?php
$array = unpack('C*', "odd string");
/*Output: Array
(
    [1] => 111
    [2] => 100
    [3] => 100
    [4] => 32
    [5] => 115
    [6] => 116
    [7] => 114
    [8] => 105
    [9] => 110
    [10] => 103
)*/

$string = pack("which format here?", $array);

echo $string;
#Desired Output: odd string
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to revert `unpack('C*', “string”)`, like this:

```
call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(array('C*'), $array )))
```

Comment: I had seen `call_user_func_array()` for pack and unpack, but never again remembered it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you, please, clarify the solution in terms of `unpack` function, but not in terms of array_merge?

Comment: @Jacobian *Oh, I see how it works* So are you still looking for a new answer, since you put the bounty in or not?

Comment: @ Rizier123. I have to wait 24 hours. before I can accept the answer

Answer (score 5):

When you're on PHP 5.6, you should consider using [argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) as it is about 4 to 5 times faster than using `call_user_func_array`:

```
pack('C*', ...$array);
```

And when you're on PHP 5.5 or lower, you should consider using `ReflectionFunction`, which seems to be a bit faster than `call_user_func_array`:

```
$packFunction = new ReflectionFunction('pack');
$packFunction->invokeArgs(array_merge(array('C*'), $array));
```