# Revert unpack('C*', "Hello world")

Tags: php

I want to revert the result of

```
unpack('C*',  "Hello world");
```

I know there is a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357008/reverting-unpackc-string), but I do not know how to apply the given answer. And by the way, the answer seems to be rather irrelevant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverting unpack('C\*', "string")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357008/reverting-unpackc-string)

Comment: If you see a question without a good answer, you can add a bounty or ask questions to the person who answered.

Comment: I started a bounty at that thread, Hope, someone will answer

Comment: Sounds good. It may take a few days for it to be noticed and you may want to say in a comment exactly what you're looking for that the accepted answer did not already provide.

Comment: @Nevermore Please remind to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). You can flag a duplicate the common way if you think it's one.