# PHP Convert byte array to int

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(235,14,123,10);
```

How can i convert php byte array to int value. I have searched lot in stackoverflow, there is no solution.

Comment: in c# is possible using Bitconverter to int

Comment: See this link , will solve your problem [How to convert byte array to integer in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683833/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-integer-in-php) or See this PHP mannual [PHP Manual, Pack data into binary string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

Comment: thanks its working now i got the solution

Comment: OK, if it helps you, then Accept this answer. Thanks