# PHP read shared memory binary data (uint32 x = shmop_read(...))

Tags: php, arrays, integer, shared-memory

I have a shared memory region which I to want access with PHP running in a web server. The shared memory is laid out where the first 4 bytes is a 32-bit unsigned integer which contains how many bytes are valid data within the remaining shared memory region (the data can be variable size), i.e.:

```
Byte Range           Value
------------------   -----------------------------------------------
0 - 3                32-bit unsigned integer - call it numBytes
4 - (numBytes + 4)   char array - The actual data, total of numBytes
```

How do I read in the first four bytes as an integer? The only thing I can think of is do a `shmop_read($key, 0, 4)` and convert the returned string value to an array, then convert that array to an integer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683833/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-integer-in-php). This all seems very messy and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Maybe it's just an `unpack("V", shmop_read($key, 0, 4));`. But could you post a `var_dump(shmop_read($key, 0, 4));`?

Comment: After looking at `unpack()` I think your answer is correct. I will not be able to test it for a day or so; unfortunately. Could you give your comment as an answer because I cannot mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just an `unpack` with `N` or `V` (depending on endianness).

So, assuming your $numBytesString looks like `\xff\xff\xff\x7f`? Then i would `unpack`:

```
$numBytesString = shmop_read($key, 0, 4);

$numBytesInt = unpack("V", $numBytesString); // assuming little-endianess

// 2147483647
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. The only thing I needed to add was `$numBytesInt = (integer) $numBytesInt[1];` because `unpack` returns an array. Although, I'm new to PHP so that last bit may not be needed.

Comment: Amazing. It was just a wild guess. Glad it worked out :)